# R - for loop - How to increment the number at the end of a Variable Name

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

Im using R. I am a beginner!
I just want to increment the number at the end of a Variable and then use this variable for an operation.

It should just go through the variables f1 ,f2 ,f3, f5...

This code doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:45) {

          e1  <- paste("f",i,sep="")

         assign(e1,with(motivnew,eval(parse(text=e1))))

         cor.test(e1, motivnew$a_dauer, method="kendall") #the operation
       }
```

i've got a Set of Data from a questionnaire. f1-45 contain the answers (1-4) from like 100 people. My goal is to see the correlations for each Question f1-f45 with another variable.

Comment: Hi there, just looking at your code, it seems like you are overwriting the variable e1 with a text value of f1,f2,f3...f45, which could be the issue. 
Can you clarify a bit more of what you are attempting to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: The combination loop + `assign` is generally discouraged because it dumps lots of objects into your global env. It's better to keep multiple outputs in a list. What's your ultimate goal? Do you want to summarize the outputs from `cor.test`?

Comment: i've got a Set of Data from a questionnaire. f1-45 contain the answers (1-4) from like 100 people. I want to have the correlations for each Question f1-f45 with another variable.

Comment: e1 is not a valid variable name here ... you need `motivnew[e1]`.  No reason to do all the eval stuff.   However you do not need to and should not do a loop for this.